# Authorization in Restful apis

Tags: rest, web, get

I am working on restul api and unable to find a solution to my prob.

I have a get request to get resource by ID, I have implemented basic authentication.

Now if somebody changes the Id in the get request , He can access resource of other users as well.

How can I restrict user to see his resources only, Do I have to create some security filter for every type of resource?

Any Link to best practises to prevent this kind of issue will be appreciated!

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: How are you getting the data by ID? Presumably from some sort of database? Ordinarily you would filter your data by that user in your repository / data access layer.

Comment: It is not for specific code.. I can give an example

Assume User1 : Authenticates himself and make a rest api call to getUser/{id}. He is allowed to access only users with Id 1 and 2. However if he changes the Id to 3 he can access it. 

To avoid it I can add a filter or interceptor the check the access first and then respond accordingly. 

My question is for each type of resource i.e User, Contact, Address I have to write this filter?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes, you need to develop something that checks for each resource if the user is actually allowed to access that resource.

If the user is not allowed, you return a `403 Forbidden` HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

If the user have access then the request should have some authorization related field as a **token** access. With it you can verify which user is requesting the data, and if it's allowed, then you continue with the GET as usual. A filter would fit perfect for this.

Check **Authorization** here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields.